# Is "I’m writing to request the username ‘log’ be released." correct?

Tags: grammaticality

This sentence left me thinking:

> I'm writing to request the username "log" be released.

Is this sentence grammatically correct, or is it missing something?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question is a little vague; what do you suppose is missing, or how else would you have phrased the sentence? Our format is not well-suited to speculation. I strongly encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: If I were to ask you if "blah blah" means what I intended it to mean how would you know?  Please edit your question to help us understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is grammatically correct.  The bare infinitive "be" is used appropriately.

The only thing you might want to add is "that"  (...request *that*.) But "that" is not required; the sentence is quite understandable without it.